# javascript: how to continuously load a page

Tags: javascript, loading

I know it sounds a bit counterintuitive,

but I'm looking for a way to have a webpage continuously loading. With this I mean I want the favicon on chrome for instance, keeping the blue animated gif.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve more specifically?

Comment: You mean pretend to be loading?

Comment: @Kaf yes I exactly want this!

Comment: That would be misleading to the user don't you think? He sees a progress where in fact nothing progresses. It's a good thing that browsers do not allow for such things to happen.

Comment: I would find an alternative means of achieving your effect. What do you mean by "keeping the blue animated gif"? Do you want the favicon to keep animating? That might be unfeasible since browsers may make the image still. Of course, it may also annoy some clients.

Comment: Mind you chrome spinning blue thingi is not a favicon. Btw, what are you trying to achieve with this? Usually people need to see the page loading done as quickly as possible. Strange !!!

Comment: Perhaps something like hellbanning? http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html

Comment: @DavidFaux I tried with a fake animated gif, but Chrome for instance doesn't allow it. For what I'm doing it's kinda crucial to have the "impression" the page is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<iframe style="display:none;" id="iframe1" src="loader.php" ></iframe>
<iframe style="display:none;" id="iframe2" src="" ></iframe>
```

Make a .php file called `loader.php`, and just enter something like this:

```
<? sleep(6); ?>
```

Then in your main page, use this:

```
// DONT FORGET TO INCLUDE JQUERY SOMEWHERE IN YOUR HEADER
<script type="text/javascript">
    var activeIframe = 2;
    var timer = 1;
    function startLoader(){
        if(activeIframe == 1){
            activeIframe = 2;
            $('#iframe1').attr('src', 'loader.php?timer='+timer);
            timer++;
        }else{
            $('#iframe2').attr('src', 'loader.php?timer='+timer);
            activeIframe = 1;
            timer++;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval("startLoader()",4000);
    });
</script>
```

This file is loaded in the first iFrame. It will be done after 6 seconds, but you will change the content of the second iFrame before that time: calling the same file after 4 seconds. Just repeat this process. The reason to use two iframes and a sleep of 6 seconds is to make sure the iframe WILL manage to load (since each div will be reloaded every 8 (4 + 4) seconds) otherwise the browser will/might crash. By using two iframes, one will always be loading while the other is allowed to finish. The `loader.php?timer=<number>` is used to stop the browser from caching the page (though I think it shouldn't be able to do this anyway since the PHP `sleep()` function is always slowing down the loading, but just to be safe)

Answer (score 1):

You can inject an iframe, and use `document.open()`:

```
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(f);
f.contentWindow.document.open();
console.log(f.contentWindow.document.readyState); // "loading"
```

To stop the loading, call `f.contentWindow.document.close();`.

The previous worked very well in Firefox 10. In Chrome, this does not work. To trick Chrome, the following can be used:

```
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.onload = function(){
    if (f.parentNode) setTimeout(function() {
        f.contentWindow.location.reload();
    },40);
};
f.src = 'about:blank';
f.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

To stop the spinning in this case, remove the `<iframe>` from the document:

```
f.parentNode.removeChild(f);
```

Comment: Dear Rob, thanks. Unfortunately while the first one works perfectly in firefox... the second one causes an ugly effect on chrome: you don't see the circle spinning but it's more like a fast refresh.

Comment: @silviolor What's the application of your code? A solution which always works is to load a page in an iframe. This page would delay the response.